# Easy way to filter a CSV file efficiently?

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a program which will filter pitches from the MLB in multiple ways. (balls, strikes, pitch type, hits, outs, ect.) Is there an easier way to filter than manually writing out every situation? Example below:

```py
#any pitch type, specific 'c' and specific 'other'
elif b == 'ALL' and c != 'any' and other != 'any':
    if a == dtdy[z]:
        #print(number[z])
        ID = number[z]
        with open('atbats.csv','r') as csvfile:
            plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            next (plots)

            for row in plots:
                #if a > k :
                if  number[z] == row[8]:
                    pitcher_atbats.append(row[0])

        with open('pitches.csv','r') as csvfile:
            plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            next (plots)
            x = []
            y = []
            pitch= []
            h = int(0)
            for row in plots:
                if h == 3000:
                    break
                else:
                    #looks for the specific values in row[4] and row[22] and
                    #will append the x and y value to respective lists
                    if (row[0] in pitcher_atbats and row[4] == other
                        and row[22] == c):
                        x.append(float(row[20]))
                        y.append(float(row[21]))
                        pitch.append(row[19])
                        #sz_bot = (float(row[26]))
                        #sz_top = (float(row[27]))
                        #print(sz_bot)
                        #bot = bot + sz_bot
                        #top = top + sz_top
                        #print(bot)
                        #if pitcher_atbats[a] == row[0]:
                        h +=1
        graph(x,y, pitch)
    else:
        z += 1
```

Can I set the filter variables, like 'c', to a value that wouldn't filter by 'c'. Otherwise, I would have to write like 50 exceptions. I'm sorry if this is confusing, I'm not sure not to explain it, but I know what I want to do.

My GitHub has the complete project: https://github.com/almostBurtMacklin/GUIpitchFinder

Comment: Use a pandas dataframe - https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @PedroLobito how would that help me? I'm getting the 'filter' from a tkinter combo box and I will be graphing the x and y using matplotlib

Comment: The object-oriented way to do this would be to determine an abstract notion of a "filter" is and operates, then implement this abstraction by defining a `class Filter`. Once that is done, instances of it for the specific kinds of filtering you wish to have done can be created and applied to the data you want processed.